# How do I call use_javascript after include_javascripts has been called?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my layout, I'm calling `include_javascripts()` in my `<head></head>` section. Later on in my layout, I'm calling a component which makes use of `use_javascript()`, but, unfortunately, the javascript has been output, so this request falls on deaf ears.

I can think of a few approaches:

1. *Put the call to `include_javascripts()` at the bottom.*
   At the moment I can't do this, because I'm using a CMS on top of symfony which uses a lot of inline javascript.
2. *Override the include_javascript helper, or create a new one, which adds doesn't add anything, but adds it adds to a queue that a filter will take care of after rendering the page.*
   This is sort of like the common filter which was removed from 1.2. Obviously, they don't seem to like this approach.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Hi, I put the include_javascripts() call in my head section too, and I've already use the use_javascript_for_form() call later. This call is similar to use_javascript I think, and it must be supposed to work. I don't know how though.

Comment: Are you using it layer in the *layout* or the *template*? The template get's rendered before the layout, so in those cases it's not an issue.

Comment: Ah ok it's because I'm using it in my layout. But what about you? Isn't your head in your layout?

Comment: Yes...but I'm including a component in my layout which uses `use_javascript`, so I thought it would be pointless to call `use_javascript` twice, once in my head, the other in the component.

Comment: It's a helper + component. The purpose of this was to create components which know how to refresh themselves with an AJAX call. They register themselves with a mediator js object...that JS should be included with the component, otherwise it won't work. I happen to be including one such refreshable component in my layout....

Comment: Ok, and why not use the `javascripts` section of your view.yml?

Answer (score 1):

The use_javascript function simply adds the specified script to a collection, which is output by the include_javascripts function.

In order to have inline javascript in your code, you will need to use  tags, since the use_javascript is pointless unless include_javascripts is called afterwards.

If you do not want to deal with filenames and such, you could always use `sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir') . js/filename.js` to grab your file.